# Correct names on trellis of levelplots

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to generate a trellis of some levelplots. Now I got 2 issues.
Here is some sampledata

```
library(lattice)
require(stats)
attach(environmental)
ozo.m <- loess((ozone^(1/3)) ~ wind * temperature * radiation,
    parametric = c("radiation", "wind"), span = 1, degree = 2)
w.marginal <- seq(min(wind), max(wind), length.out = 50)
t.marginal <- seq(min(temperature), max(temperature), length.out = 50)
r.marginal <- seq(min(radiation), max(radiation), length.out = 4)
wtr.marginal <- list(wind = w.marginal, temperature = t.marginal,
        radiation = r.marginal)
grid <- expand.grid(wtr.marginal)
grid[, "fit"] <- c(predict(ozo.m, grid))
levelplot(fit ~ wind * temperature | radiation, data = grid,
        cuts = 10, region = TRUE,
        xlab = "Wind Speed (mph)",
        ylab = "Temperature (F)",
        main = "Cube Root Ozone (cube root ppb)")
```

This will generate the following plot.[image]

1)
I want the title of every plot not to be radiation, but the value of the radiation (e.g. 7,334,...)

2) I want to change the ticks from the x and y axis to letters instead of the current numbers. (instead of 5-10-15-20 I need E-J-O-T)

Can you guys point me (once again) in the right direction?

Comment: your example is not reproducible.  Please start a new R session, then re-run your example code.

Comment: What does "change the ticks from the x and y axis to letters instead of the current numbers" mean? At the moment they seem to be degrees and miles per hour, which suggests numbers are meaningful

Comment: yeah, but this is the example, my own data is different. instead of 5-10-15-20 I need E-J-O-T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using

```
levelplot(fit ~ wind * temperature | as.factor(radiation), ... , scales= list(x=list(labels=c('','E','J','O','T'))))
```

will label your plots with the radiation value. the scales argument can be used to specify different labels.

Comment: instead of 5-10-15-20 I need E-J-O-T

Comment: @pistachionut, is there also a way to get 1 axis to have all tickmarks and the other not (like x=1,2,3,4,5,6,... and y= 5,10,15,20)?

Comment: @Sir Ksilem, not sure if i understand, something like this?
    scales= list(x= list(alternating=3, labels= c('','E','J','O','T')))

Comment: well, basically, what i need is this http://flyordie.sin.khk.be/r/circleplot.jpg but then as a levelplot. (and in a trellis)

Comment: @Sir Ksilem, i think you just need to treat x as a factor instead of a continuous numeric value, which will force trellis to label each level, so for example: levelplot(z ~ as.factor(x) + y,...)